# How does predict.pcr actually work?

Tags: r, regression, pca, prediction

In R there is this function `pcr` that runs a principal components regression. How can I use the information yielded from `pcr` in order to predict my response's value given a testset **without** using the function `predict.pcr`. I am very curious to find out. For example, below i have the first 6 components of the `pcr_model`.

```
                          1 comps       2 comps       3 comps       4 comps       5 comps      6 comps
X1                   1.402973e-05  1.638770e-05  3.025826e-05  3.843174e-05  3.893891e-05 1.058217e-04
X2                   3.585756e-06  6.721506e-06  1.424065e-05  3.192438e-05  5.830454e-05 4.251218e-04
X3                  -1.611619e-05 -1.697127e-05 -2.024606e-05 -2.847303e-05 -2.091408e-05 3.076982e-04
X4                  -1.747680e-06 -1.595572e-06 -2.301613e-07  9.525593e-05  2.357615e-04 2.249315e-04
X5                  -6.762417e-06 -8.728910e-06 -1.207538e-05  7.892716e-05  2.120044e-04 1.456909e-04
X6                  -1.069051e-06 -4.037689e-07 -4.417756e-07  1.255295e-04  2.152321e-05 4.000915e-05
```

So **instead** of going about `predict(pcr_model,testset,ncomp=3)` how would one go via a manual route? I was considering the approach as such: 
`mean(1st comp * testset,2nd comp*testset,3rd comp*testset)`. Is this approach correct? If not what is the correct one?

**EDIT**: there is a nice tutorial online that uses predict.pcr function if you would like to see a quick example https://www.r-bloggers.com/performing-principal-components-regression-pcr-in-r/

Comment: I had to do this recently for something else. Where I would start is the GitHub for the `pcr` function, which is https://github.com/cran/pls/blob/6bb2e6f6fb553883715e747bfe14b0372ed68e85/R/mvr_wrappers.R#L17, and do some digging.

Comment: i have looked at the `pcr` in Github. Either i did something wrong, for looking in the function i didn't get much help on how to go with the prediction way that I look for.

Comment: You should be able to extract the following things from your `pcr_model`: mean of the training set, PCs (that you showed in the Q), and regression coefficients. For `ncomp=3` and 6 original variables, mean `mu` is 6 dimensional vector, PCs are 6x3 matrix `V`, and regression coeffs is a 3 dimensional vector `beta`. Let's say your test data is stored in matrix `Xtest`. Then the prediction equals to: `(Xtest-mu)*V*beta` (this is pseudocode, you need to write down proper R code using matrix multiplication). It is as simple as that!!

Comment: Mhmm, makes sense, the beta you say are the regression coeffs derived from running an `lm` with the three components?

Comment: Yes. But I assume you can get it directly from the `pcr_model` object, you don't need to run `lm` yourself. Principal component regression (PCR) is by definition PCA followed by regression. So `pcr()` is doing nothing else than running first `prcomp` and then `lm`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example of doing it using entirely `base` R.  It's not exactly manual -- I use the `prcomp` function.  But it walks you through the main steps.

```
head(iris)
#outcome
y <- iris$Sepal.Length
#data
X <- model.matrix(Sepal.Length~.-1, data = iris)
#training and test sets
tr <- as.logical(1:nrow(iris) %% 2)
te <- tr == FALSE
#take principal components
pca <- prcomp(X[tr,], center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)
summary(pca)
# take first two
Xrot_tr <- pca$x[,1:2]
# do principal components regression
m <- lm(y[tr] ~ ., as.data.frame(Xrot_tr))
summary(m)
# predict for test set.  first rotate the test set according to the identified axes
Xrot_te <- predict(pca, newdata = X[te,])[,1:2]
# NB:  you could do the same thing with matrix multiplication.  First you need to scale the test set the same way as you scaled the training set
Xte <- scale(X[te,], center = pca$center, scale = pca$scale)
# then you multiply the scaled data by the rotation matrix
hard_way <- (Xte %*% pca$rotation)[,1:2]
all.equal(Xrot_te, hard_way)

# then get the predictions
pr <- predict(m, newdata = as.data.frame(Xrot_te))
# calc MSE
mean((y[te] - pr)^2)

# alternatively, you could predict without predict.lm
pr_manual <- cbind(1, hard_way) %*% as.matrix(m$coef)
head(pr_manual)
all.equal(pr, pr_manual)
# yeah whatever:
mean((pr - pr_manual)^2)
```

Comment: But still in order to go into predictions you use the `predict` function! But I want to go finding the predictions without the `predict` function!

Comment: Oh that's super easy.  Give me a sec

Comment: Updated.  In so doing I found a weird bug with linear models, and how they behave differently when fed data frames and formulas versus matrices.  Ultimately however, I would have been lost if I didn't know the math behind everything

Comment: +1 but this answer would improve if you included the same thing in math and in text. To make the prediction one needs to apply the centering and scaling from the training set, then the PCA rotation from the training set, then the linear combination from regression. Done.

Comment: So how does the math go given that you have 3 components? As in the question; in pcr i get the components (with the variable coefficients). So when i have principal component 1,2 and 3, what is the math for deriving the prediction? (cause in your example you follow the `prcomp` function, while I am curious for the way `pcr` function which both do differently.

Comment: (Also, the example that you chose is arguably suboptimal: you are predicting Sepal.Length from the dataset that includes Sepal.Length, and also you use dummy columns encoding Species, whereas PCA on such mixed data makes limited sense. This of course does not matter for the demonstration purposes.)

Comment: Woops!  Sepal length was in `X`.  Obviously IRL you'd never have your outcome in you covariates.  But the steps are the same.  Example now fixed.

Comment: @HerculesApergis choosing the number of components is just a matter of choosing how many columns of the rotated dataset to select.  Assuming that $N>p$, there will always be as many components as variables.  Like, you saw how I chose two columns?  That's taking two components.  I could have done any number.

Comment: So what is the algebra behind it when i have component 1,2 and 3 (i know we can select as many as our variable, but i select say 3 due to the highest explanation of variance) and with the testset for prediction?

Comment: Just select 3 instead of selecting 1 through 3.  Since principal components are orthogonal, you should be able to just lift the third coefficient from the regression without re-fitting the regression, but it is probably safer to re-fit the regression.  Also, don't forget the intercept.

Comment: The thing that confuses me quite a bit is that you go through the `prcomp` instead of the `pcr` version. :/

Comment: *sigh* @amoeba is right; I need to go through the math.  Not sure I have time for it right now, but I suggest that you read up on PCA and PCR.  I suggest Elements of Statistical Learning, which is free online.  Once you know what is going on, you'll be able to apply the basic idea to anybody's implementation of it.  And, if you're anything like me, you'll come to distrust packages that do too much of the work for you.  https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/

Comment: The thing is maybe i wasn't clear on what I am asking; in my question i present 6 different components. Each component as you see has the coeff for the variables. Given those components what is the method to extract the prediction. I had an assumption (which is probably wrong) that one should multiply the each component and then take the mean for the result. I think it is a simple matrix algebra that i fail to see!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67594/discussion-between-hercules-apergis-and-generic-user).