# Prediction in pcr object via pls package

Tags: r, regression, pca

I have a `data.txt` data, which shows

```
    x1  x2  x3  x4  y
    82.9    92  17.1    94  8.4
    88.0    93  21.3    96  9.6
    99.9    96  25.1    97  10.4
    105.3   94  29.0    97  11.4
    117.7   100 34.0    100 12.2
    131.0   101 40.0    101 14.2
    148.2   105 44.0    104 15.8
    161.8   112 49.0    109 17.9
    174.2   112 51.0    111 19.6
    184.7   112 53.0    111 20.8
```

Then I try the principal component regression procedure with `library(pls)` on this data as

```
d = read.table("data.txt", head=T)
X = within(d, rm(y)) 
y = d$y

pca = prcomp(X,center=T,scale=T) 
summary(pca)
k = 1 

library(pls)
pcr1 = pcr(y~., scale=T, ncomp=k, data=d)
betahat = coef(pcr1, ncomp=k, intercept=T) 
betahat
yhat1 = predict(pcr1, ncomp=k)
yhat1
yhat2 = as.matrix(cbind(1,X)) %*% betahat
yhat2
data.frame(y,yhat1,yhat2)
```

which gives

```
y y.1.comps    yhat2
8.4  8.376161 287.2186
9.6  9.352910 300.5820
10.4 10.597365 322.0072
11.4 10.817749 329.9397
12.2 12.917760 358.6413
14.2 14.120754 381.8006
15.8 16.013497 412.4796
17.9 18.622375 445.7503
19.6 19.499989 463.6031
20.8 19.981440 477.2098
```

Obviously, there must be something wrong with `yhat2`. Did I have missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a scaling issue, as is often the case when using these methods. You asked to scale the variables when calling `pcr` (`scale=T`), but your manual computation makes use of the raw (unscaled) data.

```
> pcr1 = pcr(y ~ ., ncomp = k, data = d)
> betahat = coef(pcr1, ncomp = k, intercept = T) 
--%<----------------------------------------
> data.frame(y,yhat1,yhat2)
      y y.1.comps     yhat2
1   8.4  8.414515  8.414515
2   9.6  9.121407  9.121407
3  10.4 10.513221 10.513221
4  11.4 11.139842 11.139842
5  12.2 12.722405 12.722405
6  14.2 14.285943 14.285943
7  15.8 16.265151 16.265151
8  17.9 18.022551 18.022551
9  19.6 19.353304 19.353304
10 20.8 20.461662 20.461662
```

Comment: Tks for your reply. I know your meaning. If  I insist using the  scaled one `pcr1 = pcr(y~., scale=T, ncomp=k, data=d)`, how can I manually compute back to the prediction? In fact, I also tried `yhat2 = as.matrix(cbind(1,scale(X))) %*% betahat`, but it was still incorrect

Comment: What I mean is how can I manually realize the `predict(pcr1, ncomp=k)` according to the scaled one `pcr1 = pcr(y~., scale=T, ncomp=k, data=d)` via the  `betahat = coef(pcr1, ncomp=k, intercept=T) `? @chl

Comment: I would look at the `pls:::predict.mvr` implementation details, to see how the builtin function handles centering and the intercept (and `pls:::svdpv.fit`, since `predict` without a `newdata` argument retlies on fitted values returned by this function).

Comment: Ok, I will try your hint!   I also notice [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/309626) .  Tks a lot! @chl